# Find location of a character and write location to a data frame in r

Tags: r, regex, string

Suppose this dataframe:

```
col1<- c('a_b_c_fv', 'ff_g1_h_fv','e_ii_jjjj_fv' )
df <- data.frame(col1)
```

Want to find the location of the third occurrence of the underscore _ and then write that location back to the data frame. So final result would look like:

```
df$location <- c(6,8,10)
```

How can I do this pleaase?

I have tried

```
unlist(gregexpr('_', df$col1))[3]
```

but I only get the first row location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `gregexpr` outputs a list for each vector element, you need to extract the corresponding values before `unlist`. One example to extract the information is using `sapply`.

```r
df$location <- sapply(gregexpr('_', df$col1), `[[`, 3)

df
          col1 location
1     a_b_c_fv        6
2   ff_g1_h_fv        8
3 e_ii_jjjj_fv       10
```

Comment: This appears to do what I want. But what do the double open square brackets do? `[[`, 3

Comment: Check out `?\`[[\``, it is one of the indexing operators in R to extract elements in an object, here we are extracting the third element. Also I'm using the short form of function in `sapply`, the "full version" is like `sapply(gregexpr('_', df$col1), function(x) x[[3]])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nchar` + `gsub`

```
> nchar(gsub("(([^_]+_){3}).*", "\\1", col1))
[1]  6  8 10
```

or `regexpr`

```
> attr(regexpr("([^_]+_){3}", col1), "match.length")
[1]  6  8 10
```